# Hugo static website deploying to kubernetes and expose via ingress 404 Errors

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, hugo, traefik-ingress

I’ve built a website with static content for our developers. This website is used by different type of users. Employees, dealers and ext.. and I managed this via using different config and params as below.Everything works fine when I accessed via localhost website where running as a container in my local environment or `port-forward` pods in kubernetes but when I exposed them through traefik ingress to access outside of cluster, the contents did not load properly(seems css, js and so on did not load) and I had some 404 errors as below.

[image: ![image|403x391](upload://k9oYxcZll3uyBVSTTTkShDrIZZ6.png)]

I had two different helm charts as where I had two separate pods running for different type of users.What I would like to achieve is, expose both of them through ingress such as `https://foo-example.com/employees` and `https://foo-example.com/dealers`..

What should I fix my ingress and what might be the root cause of this ?

```
├── config/
│   ├── _default
│   │   └── config.toml
│   ├── dealers 
│       ├── config.toml
│       └── params.yaml
│   └── employees
│       ├── config.toml
│       └── params.yaml
├── helm
│   └── charts
│       ├── docu-dealers
│       └── docu-employees
```

As I mentioned above when I build my image for different audience types as below where I pass it to params.yaml, it worked properly without any issue. Meanwhile everything also worked properly when I port-forward my pods.

```
  kubectl port-forward docu-plaform-dealers-docu-dealers-777bbf99-xcwl4 -n docu-platform 8084:8081
  kubectl port-forward docu-plaform-employees-docu-employees-69df858dcc-brd5g -n docu-platform 8083:8081
```

```
docker build --no-cache -t docu-platform-employees . --build-arg AUDIENCE=employees
docker run -p 8081:8081 --name docu-platform-employees -d docu-platform-employees
```

So here is my dockerfile.

```
FROM alpine:latest as build
#Label maintainer for this dockerfile
LABEL maintainer="Semih Ural <semih.ural@daimler.com>"
#Set environment variable for hugo version and directory
ENV HUGO_VERSION=0.78.0 \
    HUGO_SITE=/src/hugo
#Set arguments for run hugo
ARG AUDIENCE
RUN sed -i.bak 's+https://+http://+' /etc/apk/repositories
#Install dependencies
RUN apk --no-cache add \
    curl \
    git \
    libc6-compat \
    libstdc++ \
    nodejs \
    npm
#Create dir for hugo app
WORKDIR ${HUGO_SITE}
#create package.json
COPY package.json ./
#Install npm depedencies for scss
RUN npm install -D --save postcss 
RUN npm install -D autoprefixer 
RUN npm install -D --save postcss-cli
#Install hugo extended version
RUN curl -L https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v${HUGO_VERSION}/hugo_extended_${HUGO_VERSION}_Linux-64bit.tar.gz \
    -o /tmp/hugo.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzf /tmp/hugo.tar.gz -C /tmp \
    && cp /tmp/hugo /usr/local/bin/ \
    && apk del curl git\
    && mkdir -p ${HUGO_SITE} \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*
#Copy hugo to container
COPY . ${HUGO_SITE}
#Build hugo with environment variable
RUN hugo -e ${AUDIENCE}

#Prepare nginx
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=build /src/hugo/public /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN chgrp -R root /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx && \
    chmod -R 770 /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx

#Fire up nginx
EXPOSE 8081
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Here is my nginx.conf

```
server {

  listen 8081;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;    
  }

  location = /status {
    access_log off;
    default_type text/plain;
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 “alive”;
  }

  location = /50x.html {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Here are the ingress.

```
# Source: docu-dealers/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: RELEASE-NAME-docu-dealers
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: docu-dealers
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    helm.sh/chart: docu-dealers-0.1.0
    traffic-type: external
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
    - host: foo-example.com
      http:
        paths: 
          - path: /dealers
            backend:
              serviceName: docu-plaform-dealers-docu-dealers
              servicePort: 80
```

---

```
# Source: docu-employees/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: RELEASE-NAME-docu-employees
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: docu-employees
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    helm.sh/chart: docu-employees-0.1.0
    traffic-type: external
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
    - host: foo-example.com
      http:
        paths: 
          - path: /employees
            backend:
              serviceName: docu-plaform-employees-docu-employees
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Can you check the path of the requests going into 404? Is the path correct? You Ingress files serve the apps under subpaths, do the pages expect that when loading additional resources? Or are they trying to request resources under / ?

Comment: @AndD, seems correct, at least when I compared the one that I accessed via localhost through port-forwarding and ingress for logo, the requested url is same.

`https://foo-example.com/images/intro_oneapi_logo.png`
`http://localhost:8081/images/intro_oneapi_logo.png`

Comment: Then there's a problem, because your ingress is serving things under subpaths, if you request the logo at https://foo-example.com/employees/images/intro_oneapi_logo.png does it work?

Comment: @AndD, yeap that worked but I could not find a way to expose like that.. I tried rewrite annotation but it did not work for me as well

Comment: Can you check your index.html page ad see if it requests the logo at /images/intro_oneapi_logo.png or at images/intro_oneapi_logo.png ? Notice the initial slash difference

Comment: @AndD, it worked when I added below annotation for my ingress
`traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: PathPrefixStrip`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228366/discussion-between-semural-and-andd).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug is to put traefik into debug mode.

cli:

```
--accesslog
--log
--log.level=DEBUG
```

After this, you would just get the pod's logs:

```
kubectl logs pod/traefik-XYZ-ABC -n namespace -f
```

And second is to use IngressRoutes versus Ingress.
An example you can find here:
https://github.com/sleighzy/k3s-traefik-v2-kubernetes-crd

You would use a match like:

```
match: Host(`foo.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/dealers`)
```